# Transparent form with parent

Tags: forms, transparency, delphi-xe2, flicker

I am trying to avoid flickering, so I decided to use transparent forms. The problem is that forms are not being painted properly. [image]

And if I show form manually using BitBtn1Click:[image]

The question is how do I paint forms correctly and without flickering? Solution should work if i hide previous transparent form and show new one on its place.

[image]

This is Main form

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Transparent1, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    imgBackground: TImage;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FfrmTransparent1: TfrmTransparent1;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  JPEG;

procedure TfrmMain.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
FfrmTransparent1.Show;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  imgBackground.Align := alClient;
  imgBackground.Picture.LoadFromFile('butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg');
  Self.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMaximized;

  FfrmTransparent1:= TfrmTransparent1.Create(nil);
  FfrmTransparent1.Parent := Self;
  FfrmTransparent1.Left := 10;
  FfrmTransparent1.Top := 20;
  //FfrmTransparent1.Show;
  //FfrmTransparent1.Update;
end;

end.
```

DFM

```
object frmMain: TfrmMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'frmMain'
  ClientHeight = 423
  ClientWidth = 624
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object imgBackground: TImage
    Left = 120
    Top = 152
    Width = 105
    Height = 105
  end
  object BitBtn1: TBitBtn
    Left = 541
    Top = 16
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'BitBtn1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = BitBtn1Click
  end
end
```

Transparent form

```
unit Transparent1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmTransparent1 = class(TForm)
    imgButterfly: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  PNGImage;

procedure TfrmTransparent1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Brush.Style:=bsClear;
  Self.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  imgButterfly.Picture.LoadFromFile('Butterfly.png');
  imgButterfly.Left := 20;
  imgButterfly.Top := 30;
  imgButterfly.Height := imgButterfly.Picture.Height;
  imgButterfly.Width := imgButterfly.Picture.Width;
  Self.Width := imgButterfly.Width + imgButterfly.Left;
  Self.Height := imgButterfly.Top + imgButterfly.Height;
end;

end.
```

DFM

```
object frmTransparent1: TfrmTransparent1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'frmTransparent1'
  ClientHeight = 292
  ClientWidth = 502
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object imgButterfly: TImage
    Left = 16
    Top = 16
    Width = 217
    Height = 89
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see anything going transparent here. Sounds to me like your solution is wrong and that there is more point in continuing to flog the dead horse.

Comment: What would be "right" solution?

Comment: First of all we would need to know what the problem was. At present we have a failed solution to a problem which we do not understand.

Comment: I am writing an application that will work in terminal (the one you see at shops). When user clicks a button, next screen is shown. I want it not to flicker when screen is shown.